# extract minimum value from array using 2 index

Tags: python, numpy

I have a table where x and y represent respectively the head of the rows and the head of the columns. Using two index (x1,y1) I have to enter in the table and select the minimum value that is reported in z. In order to be more clear, with x1 I will identify the i and i+1 rows, with y1 the j and j+1 columns, it means four values in z and I need to extract only the minimum between them.

this is the table:

```
x = np.array([100., 200., 300., 400., 500., 600.])
y = np.array([20., 300., 450., 500., 550.])
z = np.array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.02, 1.05],
              [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.01, 1.05],
              [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.01, 1.04],
              [1., 1., 1., 1.01, 1.07, 1.18],
              [1., 1., 1., 1.01, 1.09, 1.23]])
```

for

```
x1, y1 = 550, 525
```

I would like to find the minimum value in `z`. 
For instance, in this case should be `1.07`.

Thanks to your comments and, in particular, the indication of Toby Speight, I have improved the code in this way:

```
x = np.array([100., 200., 300., 400., 500., 600.])

y = np.array([20., 300., 450., 500., 550.])

z = np.array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.02, 1.05],
              [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.01, 1.05],
              [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.01, 1.04],
              [1., 1., 1., 1.01, 1.07, 1.18],
              [1., 1., 1., 1.01, 1.09, 1.23]])



xmin, xmax = 100,600
ymin, ymax = 20, 550

x1, y1 = 600, 350

if x1 > xmax:
   x1 = xmax
   if x1 < xmin:
      x1 = xmin
else:
   x1 = x1      

if y1 > ymax:
   y1 = ymax
   if y1 < ymin:
      y1 = ymin    
else:
  y1 = y1  


xi = max([0]+[i for i in range(len(x)) if x1 >= x[i]])
yi = max([0]+[i for i in range(len(y)) if y1 >= y[i]])

z1 = z[yi, xi]

print z1
```

for sure it is not elegant (I am not an expert!) but it works very well in all the cases except for x1, y1 = 600, 350 in which the expected results should be `z1 = z[yi, xi] = 1.04`.

I hope that I was clearer this time!

If you can help me, I will be grateful to you!
Many thanks guys!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Why is 1.07 the minimum of z? What is the relation between x, y and x1, y1 and what do they have to do with the minimum of z?

Comment: Please add some relevant code?

Comment: I think if you add more context and connect the missing pieces there might be some answers coming along or hints. Curious what you tried already.

Comment: sorry if I was not clear. Practically I have a table where x and y represent respectively the head of the rows and the head of the  columns. using two index (x1,y1) I have to enter in the table and select the minimum value that is reported in z. In order to be more clear, with x1 I will identify the i and i+1 rows, with y1 the j and j+1 columns, it means for valus in z and I need to extract only the minimum between them.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add this explanation; thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xindex = max([0]+[i for i in range(len(x)) if x1 >= x[i]])
yindex = max([0]+[i for i in range(len(y)) if y1 >= y[i]])
print z[yindex][xindex]
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
col = np.searchsorted(x, x1)
row = np.searchsorted(y, y1)
result = z[row - 1, col - 1]
```

Note that you still have some work to do to handle edge cases, for instance when `x1` is less than the first value in `x`.